# Put specific lines into an array

Tags: python

I have a file which is like:

> 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5
>
> 1 0.1
>
> 0.6 0.6 0.6 0.6
>
> 1 0.2

So my question is I just want the lines with "0.5" and "0.6" and put them in a array which would be like

> 0.5 0.5 0.5
>
> 0.6 0.6 0.6

How should I do this?
I have tried several methods such as readlines and row.split, but I just cannot get the right form. Maybe I did not write the correct form of readlines and row.split.

Comment: You should share the code you have attempted

Comment: Will `0.5` or `0.6` always be at the _beginning_ of the line?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can do this by going over all the lines, and checking if the lines start with your desired variables, for your case (`text.txt` is the name of your presumed file):

```
with open('text.txt') as f:
    l = [var.rstrip() for var in f if var.startswith(('0.5','0.6'))]
    print(l)
```

Comment: [startswith](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) accepts prefix tuples

Comment: @1_CR How can I use that to make this answer better? If you've got suggestions, I'm more than willing to listen.

Comment: `var.startswith(('0.5', '0.6'))` instead of `var.startswith('0.5') or var.startswith('0.6')`

Comment: @1_CR Thanks! :D I learnt something new from you today. Much appreciated.

Comment: you're welcome. However , please note you need `var.startswith(('0.5', '0.6'))` not `var.startswith('0.5','0.6')`

Answer (score 1):

These solutions will check for `0.5` and `0.6` at any position in the line, not just at the start.

Using `str.split`:

```
with open('filename') as f:
    lis = []
    for line in f:
       spl = line.split()
       if '0.5' in spl or '0.6' in spl:
           lis.append(line.strip())
```

Using `regex` with word boundaries:

```
import re
with open('filename') as f:
    lis = []
    for line in f:
       if re.search(r'\b(0\.6|0\.5)\b', line):
           lis.append(line.strip())
```

Comment: Great answer, but rather strange coming from a man who can't stop list-comprehensions from coming out of his sleeves ;)

Answer (score 1):

This does it:

```
with open("/path/to/file") as f:
    print [l.strip() for l in f if " 0.5 " in l or " 0.6 " in l]
```

Output:

```
['0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5', '0.6 0.6 0.6 0.6']
```

---

**Edit based off of comments:**

Note that the above solution is for if the data is like that given.  If it isn't, then you will need something a little more powerful:

```
from re import search
with open("/path/to/file") as f:
    print [l.strip() for l in f if search(r"\b0\.[56]\b", l)]
```

This will match for `"0.5"` or `"0.6"` anywhere in the string and will work for cases such as `"0.5\n"` and `"0.6\n"`.

Comment: Your updated solution won't match `0.5`, `0.6` at the start of the string.

Comment: what about `0.5\n`? ;-)